# Get properties from object that contains specific string

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```
v = {
    x1: "x",
    x1_trust: "y",
    x2: "something",
    x2_trust: "something_else"
}
```

Is it possible to create a new object with the properties that contains "_trust"? I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: search for cloning an object and filtering. You'll get a clue

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()` and  `reduce()` to create new object and `indexOf()` to check if object key contains substring.

```js
var v = {
  x1: "x",
  x1_trust: "y",
  x2: "something",
  x2_trust: "something_else"
}

var newObj = Object.keys(v).reduce(function(r, key) {
  if (key.indexOf('_trust') != -1) r[key] = v[key];
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! This is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var v = {
  x1: "x",
  x1_trust: "y",
  x2: "something",
  x2_trust: "something_else"
};

var op = Object.keys(v).reduce(function(a, b) {
  return (b.indexOf('_trust') > -1) && (a[b] = v[b]), a;
}, {});

console.log(op);
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now!

Answer (score 0):

do you want to make a new object which only has _trust keys and values taken from your object v?
if that is the case then try this code please (using jquery)

```
v = {
    x1: "x",
    x1_trust: "y",
    x2: "something",
    x2_trust: "something_else"
}

var newJson = {};
jQuery.each(v, function(key, val) {
    if(key.indexOf("_trust") > -1){
        newJson[key] = val;
    }
});
```